# Crear campo tipo date que solo contenga mes y año

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

Buen día a todos, necesito bloquear la opción de seleccionar el día en un objeto `Ext.form.DateField`, ya que solo quiero seleccionar el mes y el año. Estoy usando `ExtJS 3.4`. De ante mano les doy las gracias a quien me pueda ayudar.

```
new Ext.form.DateField({
    format     : "F, Y",
    width      : 120,
    id         : "cmpFechaInicio",
    allowBlank : false,
    showToday  : false,
    applyTo    : "MyInformeFiltroFechaInicio",
    editable   : false
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hace tiempo miré este ejemplo que puede servirte, donde se define el DateField:

```
Ext.define('Ext.form.field.Month', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Date',
    alias: 'widget.monthfield',
    requires: ['Ext.picker.Month'],
    alternateClassName: ['Ext.form.MonthField', 'Ext.form.Month'],
    selectMonth: null,
    createPicker: function() {
        var me = this,
            format = Ext.String.format;
        return Ext.create('Ext.picker.Month', {
            pickerField: me,
            ownerCt: me.ownerCt,
            renderTo: document.body,
            floating: true,
            hidden: true,
            focusOnShow: true,
            minDate: me.minValue,
            maxDate: me.maxValue,
            disabledDatesRE: me.disabledDatesRE,
            disabledDatesText: me.disabledDatesText,
            disabledDays: me.disabledDays,
            disabledDaysText: me.disabledDaysText,
            format: me.format,
            showToday: me.showToday,
            startDay: me.startDay,
            minText: format(me.minText, me.formatDate(me.minValue)),
            maxText: format(me.maxText, me.formatDate(me.maxValue)),
            listeners: {
                select: {
                    scope: me,
                    fn: me.onSelect
                },
                monthdblclick: {
                    scope: me,
                    fn: me.onOKClick
                },
                yeardblclick: {
                    scope: me,
                    fn: me.onOKClick
                },
                OkClick: {
                    scope: me,
                    fn: me.onOKClick
                },
                CancelClick: {
                    scope: me,
                    fn: me.onCancelClick
                }
            },
            keyNavConfig: {
                esc: function() {
                    me.collapse();
                }
            }
        });
    },
    onCancelClick: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.selectMonth = null;
        me.collapse();
    },
    onOKClick: function() {
        var me = this;
        if (me.selectMonth) {
            me.setValue(me.selectMonth);
            me.fireEvent('select', me, me.selectMonth);
        }
        me.collapse();
    },
    onSelect: function(m, d) {
        var me = this;
        me.selectMonth = new Date((d[0] + 1) + '/1/' + d[1]);
    }
});
```

Y posteriormente lo crea mandandolo a llamar de la siguiente forma:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Month', {
    format: 'F, Y',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Te dejo el link de la respuesta:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167452/extjs-5-date-picker-year-and-month-only

Y el link del funcionamiento del código:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/h5i&view/editor

Espero te ayude.